# Как убрать белый прямоугольник на фоне текста и увеличить шрифт в toolbar

Tags: java, android

Есть некая проблема: при смене фона в тулбаре на черный или темный при помощи кнопки(т.е. смена темы), появляется на фоне текста белый прямоугольник и шрифт уменьшается(см фото).
Вот код styles.xml

```
<style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#4d5056</item>
        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#4d5056</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#009688</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AMOLEDTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item>
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/ToolBarAMOLED</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#2b2e30</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#2b2e30</item>
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/ToolBarDark</item>
    </style>

<style name="ToolBarLight">
        <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolBarAMOLED">
        <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolBarDark">
        <item name="android:background">#2b2e30</item>
    </style>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    app:titleTextColor="#616266"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ToolBarLight"
    android:elevation="0.5dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image: Вот что происходит при смене темы]

Comment: Вопрос про слово темы? Тогда почему бы не обрезать скриншот, оставив только нужное, чтобы не заставлять других пользователей искать о каком именно тексте речь? Про код мистической кнопки, которая непонятно что делает, даже говорить не буду.

Comment: Я кажется четко дал понять о чем в моей просьбе о помощи идет речь, причем еще в вопросе.Какой еще код мистической кнопки?Там нет ничего мистического, все просто и понятно